# Form select being populated in an odd manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select form which is populated oddly. I was wondering whether I could get an explanation.

**Schema:**

I have a User model which has a many to many with a model called Conversations. Conversations in turn has_many Messages and Messages belongs to Conversations. User and Messages have no links other than that.

**Message controller**

I am debugging a small messaging system so I decided to pass in all users (I know, I know) to my view just so I could display them in a dropdown and test send messages to them. Basically just

```
def new    
  @message = Message.new
  @users = User.all
end
```

For some odd reason I have to have `belongs_to :user` in my Message class or I get the error `undefined method "user" for #<Message:0x0000000581b898>`

**View**

In my form I basically have

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.select :user, collection: @users.all.map { |user| [user.id, user.name] }%>
</div>

Other nonsense

<% end %>
```

**Problem**

So when generating a new message why is my dropdown being populated like its trying to access `Message.User.id` rather than just User.id if I am giving the correct data with `@users= User.all` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the form builder instance `f` to define `select` for `:user`.  If you don't want to associate `:user` with `message`, you could use [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag).

```
<%= select_tag :user, options_for_select(@users.all.map { |user| [user.id, user.name] }) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your form is trying to access the user method/attribute of your message object.

`f.select :user`